# Spring cloud openfeign 3.0.1 fallback not being triggered

Tags: spring-cloud

I'm using the version 3.0.1 of spring-cloud-starter-openfeign and I'm having problems with the fallback implementation. Seems it's not being triggered if any exception occurs.

I've configured a feign client with an invalid host as url in order to provoke an exception:

```
@FeignClient(name = "feignClientTest", url = "invalid.url", fallback = FeignClientTest.FallbackTest.class)
public interface FeignClientTest {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/fake/url")
    String getFromFakeUrl();

    @Component
    class FallbackTest implements FeignClientTest {

        private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

        @Override
        public String getFromFakeUrl() {
            log.debug("Fallback occurred for getFromFakeUrl");
            return "Fallback";
        }
    }
}
```

After calling getFromFakeUrl() method, I get an java.net.UnknownHostException instead of the "Fallback" string used in the fallback implementation.

I set feign.circuitbreaker.enabled=true in application configuration file.

Should I configure anything more? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your dependencies

Answer (score 10):

I came across the same issue after upgrading project to Spring Cloud to 2021 release train, which doesn't support hystrix and `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix` anymore.

In  [spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-cloud-feign-circuitbreaker) I have found this info:

> If Spring Cloud CircuitBreaker is on the classpath and feign.circuitbreaker.enabled=true, Feign will wrap all methods with a circuit breaker.

This means you have to meet two requirements:

1. Enable property: `feign.circuitbreaker.enabled=true`
2. Add dependency to Spring Cloud CircuitBreaker, which will handle configured fallbacks.

In my case I have switched to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Which resolved the issue.

Comment: Adding "spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j" works for me. Note that the dependency is a transitive dependency of "spring-cloud-dependencies".

Answer (score 0):

At the end I fixed the issue adding the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

With newer version of Spring, property mentioned by @akoz is changed to:

```
spring.cloud.openfeign.circuitbreaker.enabled=true
```